# Can I assign an XML parsing error to a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I occasionally receive an XML Parsing error from a JavaScript login method, and I'm FINE with the parsing error, but I'd like to be able to catch it and do something if it exists.

something like:

```
if (error.startsWith("XML Parsing Error")){
    alert("there was a parsing error");
}
```

My question is: Can I assign the actual XML Parsing error text to a JS variable?

Sorry if this seems dumb (it probably is)

thanks

Comment: The answer is yes, as long as the error object thrown has a property that contains the error text (or if the error object is itself a string).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to your login function in a `try..catch`:

```
try {
    login();
}
catch (err) {
    if (err.message.substr(0, 17) == "XML Parsing Error") {
        alert("there was a parsing error");
    }
}
```

JavaScript passes an [`Error` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dww52sbt%28VS.94%29.aspx) to the catch statement.  Define the variable name between the parentheses (eg, `err` as above).  You now have the error in a variable and can use it how you like.  You can, of course, also store any of the `Error` object's properties in a variable.

```
var errMsg = err.message;
```